# Append nones to list if is too short

Tags: python

Is it possible to improve this bit?

```
def append_nones(length, list_):
    """
    Appends Nones to list to get length of list equal to `length`.
    If list is too long raise AttributeError
    """
    if len(list_) < length:
        nones = length - len(list_)
        return list_ + [None] * nones
    elif len(list_) > length:
        raise AttributeError('Length error list is too long.')
    else:
        return list_
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### 1. Comments on your code

1. The documentation does not match the implementation. The docstring says "append Nones to list" but it does not append: if the list does not have the required length, it returns a newly allocated list.
2. It seems wrong to return the original list if it was the right length, but return a newly allocated list if it was too short. For consistency, the function should either always return a new list, or always (update and) return the old list.
3. It's a loss of generality to support only the addition of `None` elements. Why not let the caller pass in their preferred placeholder element.
4. If you run `help(AttributeError)` you'll see that its description is "Attribute not found." This does not seem appropriate here. `ValueError` would be a better choice, or better still, create your own.
5. There's no need to name the variable `list_`: this avoids shadowing the built-in function `list`, but you don't use that function, so it doesn't matter if you shadow it.
6. You call `len(list_)` three times. Simpler to call it once and store the value.
7. The case `len(list_) == length` could be combined with the case `len(list_) < length` and so simplify the code.
8. The error message "Length error list is too long" makes no sense in English.
9. The error message would be more useful if it contained the actual numbers.
10. This kind of function is ideal for [doctests](http://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html).

#### 2. Revised code

I've chosen to make the function always update its argument, and fixed all the problems noted above.

```
class TooLongError(ValueError):
    pass

def pad(seq, target_length, padding=None):
    """Extend the sequence seq with padding (default: None) so as to make
    its length up to target_length. Return seq. If seq is already
    longer than target_length, raise TooLongError.

    >>> pad([], 5, 1)
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    >>> pad([1, 2, 3], 7)
    [1, 2, 3, None, None, None, None]
    >>> pad([1, 2, 3], 2)
    ... # doctest: +IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      ...
    TooLongError: sequence too long (3) for target length 2

    """
    length = len(seq)
    if length > target_length:
        raise TooLongError("sequence too long ({}) for target length {}"
                           .format(length, target_length))
    seq.extend([padding] * (target_length - length))
    return seq
```

Answer (score 3):

What you've done looks good to me.

However, here's what I would do if I were to write the same function :

```
def append_nones(length, list_):
    """
    Appends Nones to list to get length of list equal to `length`.
    If list is too long raise AttributeError
    """
    diff_len = length - len(list_)
    if diff_len < 0:
        raise AttributeError('Length error list is too long.')
    return list_ + [None] * diff_len
```

The main point is to handle a smaller number of cases.

From the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) :

> Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.

Answer (score -1):

```
def nones(length,mylist):
    if len(mylist) > length:
        raise AttributeError('Length error list is too long.')
    for i in range(length):
        try: yield mylist[i]
        except IndexError: yield None


print list(nones(20,[1,2,3]))
```

it doesnt exactly match what you described but this is the implementation I would probably use

I would also probably change

```
if len(mylist) > length:
    raise AttributeError('Length error list is too long.')
```

to

```
assert len(mylist) <= length,"list is too long"
```